# cakephp $this->redirect() not working on server

Tags: cakephp

I have inserted data in table using $this->query() and then display data on page, but it does not displaying latest insert data. When I refresh the page then it display latest insert data. So I have redirect to the same page using $this->redirect() but it shows a blank page.

Comment: You can use Ajax to display data on page without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

Add the current page url as a parameter to `$this->refresh`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#flow-control

Either something like

`$this->redirect('/customers/index');`

or

`$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'index'))
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why this answers the question?