# $this->query() not displaying latest inserted data

Tags: cakephp

I have inserted data in table using $this->query() and then display data on page, but it does not displaying latest insert data. When I refresh the page then it display latest insert data. What I can do in this case

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp $this->redirect() not working on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734245/cakephp-this-redirect-not-working-on-server)

Comment: You need to paste your code or explain why what I suggested in the first question did not work. Don't just create duplicate questions with the same description